# Can grilled steak be eaten next day if refrigerated and the heated in the oven?

Tags: food-safety

I grilled a few beef steaks on the electric grill and then kept it in the freezer. Can it be eaten for next few days , by heating in the oven? Thanks!

FF

Answer (score 2):

You certainly *can* do that, but if you are going to eat the steaks within three days I don't see the point of freezing them, it would be better to leave them in the refrigerator. But heating from frozen is safe. USDA guidelines are a little weird on reheating frozen food, personally I wouldn't even go there. If they were fine when they went into the freezer (or fridge in the last 3 days), they will be fine when you take them out. Just heat to the point of tastiness.

Answer (score 0):

I think low and slow in the oven will produce the best result. You're just reheating to serving temperature so I wouldn't push the oven beyond 200-225 F.

If it's cooked, there's little danger from bacterial infection. What kills the flavor of steak (or chicken, or any other protein) is oxygen, which turns it rancid. Wrap as tightly as possible or use a vacuum sealer. If you're only storing for a few days, the best way is to actualy put in a sealed container and pour in enough stock to cover. This is an effective barrier against oxygen and eliminates the need to thaw.